# Get dialog result of SSRS parameter form

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

From a report controller object, I'm trying to figure out how to find out if the user has canceled the SSRS report dialog screen or if they hit OK.

In AX, I'm trying to write a controller that will execute two different designs of the same report object, both will use the same contract (parameters).  So far I have this code:

```
cusController controller;
cusContract   contract;

//Run Format 1
controller = new cusController();
controller.initController(_args);
controller.parmReportName(ssrsReportStr(cusReport, Format1));
controller.parmShowDialog(true);
controller.startOperation();

//Run Format 2
contract = controller.parmReportContract().parmRdpContract() as cusContract;
contract.parmFormat(cusReportFormat::Format2);
controller = new cusController();

controller.initController(_args);
controller.parmReportName(ssrsReportStr(cusReport, Format2));
controller.parmShowDialog(false);
controller.parmReportContract().parmRdpContract(contract);
controller.startOperation();
```

The above works perfect when the user enters in parameters and hits OK.  However, when the user hits Cancel the first report cancels, but since the second report has parmShowDialog(false), it doesn't know the first report was canceled.  Any ideas on how to capture the Cancel from the first report?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what your controller class extends, I think you would do something like this.  I've seen it done a ton of different ways:

```
    SysOperationStartResult         result;

    // Method 1
    result = controller.startOperation();
    if (result == SysOperationStartResult::Started ||
        result == SysOperationStartResult::AddedToBatchQueue)
    {
        info("They clicked ok");
    }

    // Method 2
    if (controller.prompt())
    {
        controller.run();
        info("They clicked ok");
    }
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, I was not aware of the return type of startOperation(), this did the trick.

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Comment: Actually, I take it back. This doesn't appear to work.  When I hit the Close button on the report, the result comes back as Canceled even though the report went thru execution.  Back to the drawing board :/

Comment: Did you try the second method? That doesn't seem right that the report would execute and return canceled...seems like something else is up. Would need to see code in its entirety to really know.